# Differential form relation from conserved angular momentum

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

In Binney and Tremaine chapter 3 equation 3.9 they use the fact that in a spherically symmetric potential you get from the Euler Lagrange equations that angular momentum is conserved $$r^2 \dot{\phi}=L $$

then it is said that this relation follows $$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{L}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\phi}$$ but I do not see how.

I tried to derive it the following way
$$r^2 \frac{d\phi}{dt}=L $$
$$r^2 \frac{d\phi}{dt} \frac{d}{d \phi}=L \frac{d}{d \phi} $$
$$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{L}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\phi}$$

But I do not understand what multiplying by $\frac{d}{d\phi}$ means and why it is legal. Since we have not acted the derivative on anything yet, I cannot use the limit definition to view it as a fraction. the lone $d$ in the numerator is concerning me.

Comment: \begin{aligned}\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{du}{d\phi }\dfrac{d\phi }{dt}\\
\dfrac{d\phi }{dt}=\dfrac{L}{r^{2}}\\
\dfrac{d}{dt}=\dfrac{L}{r^{2}} \dfrac{d}{d\phi }\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation:
$$\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{L}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\phi}$$ is just an operator that satisfies any function $f(\phi(t))$. In other words, any function that can be expanded via multivariable chain rule. The equation is not something you can work with without inputting some scalar $f$. By default, it is written this way to make it clear that there's more than one satisfactory function (such as radius $r(\phi(t))$ in orbits).
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{dt}\frac{df}{d\phi}$$
$$L=r^2\frac{d\phi}{dt}\implies\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{L}{r^2}$$